# Block works when directly used but not when used in a function

Tags: programming

I want to calculate a derivative such as: $\delta f=\sum_{i=A,B} \sum_{k=1,2,3}  \frac{\partial f}{\partial a_k^i}$. 
Since $ a_k^i$ are assigned values other places in the code, I have used `Block`. I obtain correct  results for $\delta f$ directly calculating a function. However, when I define a function `deltaf` which is suppose to do the same thing I don't get the correct results.

Here are the values of `a[i,k]`

```
a[A, 1] = 1; a[A, 2] = 2; a[A, 3] = 3;
a[B, 1] = 5; a[B, 2] = 10; a[B, 3] = 15;
```

As a sample function for which I want the derivative of, I use `f1[i,x]`

```
f1[i_, x_] := (1 - x)*Sum[a[i, k]^2, {k, 1, 3}]
```

Using `Block` works for getting the derivative of `f1[A,x]` with respect to `a[i,k]` (I emphasize that I'm calculating `f1[A,x]` and not `f1[i,x]`):

```
Block[{a},Sum[D[f1[A, x], a[i, k]], {i, {A, B}}, {k, {1, 2, 3}}]]
```

> ```
> 12 (1 - x)
> ```

However if I define a function that does the same thing:

```
deltaf[f_] := Block[{a}, Sum[D[f, a[i, k]], {i, {A, B}}, {k, {1, 2, 3}}]]
```

It doesn't give the correct value anymore:

```
deltaf[f1[A, x]]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

Why is this happening?
How is it that when I calculate the same thing directly I get a correct answer but not when defined as a function?

Comment: Hi ! As this is a Q&A site you should also explicitly state what are you trying to do - e.g ask a question, not just leave it blank.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question. My question is exactly why this is happening. In other words the same thing as mentioned in the title: "Why does Block not work when used as a function? But it works when directly used? "

Comment: Did you try `deltaf[Evaluate[f1[A, x]]]`?

Comment: Yes I did but it still didn't work! @Sosi

Comment: Actually, I think you want the exact opposite of what I was suggesting. Notice that when you do  `deltaf[f1[A,x]]` you are evaluating `D[f, a[i, k]]` (=`14 (1 - x)`) AND THEN using this result to compute the `Sum`. This is why the derivative then gives 0, because you are evaluating the derivatives of `14(1-x)` with respect to `a[i,k]`.

Comment: would this be anything of what you want? (yes, I know it's a different approach :) ) `Clear@ble;
ble[j_, k_] := Block[{a, myf},
  myf[i_, x_] := (1 - x)*Sum[a[i, k]^2, {k, 1, 3}];
  Sum[D[myf[A, x], a[i, k]], {i, {A, B}}, {k, {1, 2, 3}}]
  ]
ble[A, x]`

Comment: The problem is that in general I will be using different functions which don't necessarily have the same parameter dependence as `f1[A,x]`. Namely I will also deal with functions such as `f2[A,x,y,B,z]`. @Sosi

Comment: It seems that doing `SetAttributes[deltaf, HoldAll];` solves the problem, thanks to @IstvánZachar  (http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21216245#21216245)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Both to you and IstvánZachar. It worked like a charm. I'm absolutely new to stackexchange and have no idea how to choose this as an answer or if that's even what should be done. @Sosi

Comment: Usually, depending on the question, I like to wait one day to see if other people answer differently or make suggestions before accepting an answer. After that, I usually accept it as long as it really answers my question :)
To choose it as an answer just click the *checkmark* near the arrows on the left side of the answer. It should become green, meaning it was accepted.
And welcome @nein! The chat (http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/wolfram-mathematica) is also good and is full of people who are happy to help in simple questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(this answer resumes the discussions over at the comments and over the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21216245#21216245). Thanks to @IstvánZachar for helping out and for suggesting my posting it as answer).

The problem is that `deltaf[f1[A,x]]` evaluates `f1[A,x]` (=`14 (1 - x)`) before actually computing `Sum[D[f, a[i, k]], {i, {A, B}}, {k, {1, 2, 3}}]`. Specifying that the attributes of `deltaf` are to remain unevaluated solves the problem:

```
SetAttributes[deltaf, HoldAll];
deltaf[f_] := Block[{a}, Sum[D[f, a[i, k]], {i, {A, B}}, {k, {1, 2, 3}}]];

deltaf[f1[A, x]]
```

> ```
> 12 (1 - x)
> ```